# error in my SQL syntax in GetCountry query

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, syntax-error

I am getting a syntax error in my code. An error comes up at the line `adapter.Fill(dt);` right after the `adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT c.*,(Select Initials FROM users....` line. The error says check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '237 ORDER BY c.CountryName' at line 1 but I'm not sure what is causing this error

```
public static string GetCountry(int CountryID)
{
    string Country = "";

    string sql = "proc_GetCountries";

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(sql, DataUtils.ConnectionStrings["TAT"]))
    {
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM countries WHERE ID = ?countryID ORDER BY CountryName";
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("countryID", CountryID));
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Country = dt.Rows[0]["CountryName"].ToString();
        }
    }
    return Country;
}
public static DataSet GetCountry(int Company_ID, int ID)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    string sql = "proc_GetCountry";

    DataTable dt = new DataTable(), dtRates = new DataTable(), dtDepots = new DataTable();

    using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(sql, DataUtils.ConnectionStrings["TAT"]))
    {
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT c.*,(Select Initials FROM users WHERE User_ID = c.CreatedByUser) AS CreatedBy, (SELECT Initials FROM users WHERE User_ID = c.ModifiedByUser) AS ModifiedBy " +
            "FROM countries c WHERE c.Company_ID = ?company_ID AND c.ID ?iD ORDER BY c.CountryName";
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("company_ID", Company_ID));
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("iD", ID));
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    }
    //Rates
    using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(sql, DataUtils.ConnectionStrings["TAT"]))
    {
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT cc.* FROM country_rates cc WHERE cc.CountryID ?iD";
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("iD", ID));
        adapter.Fill(dtRates);
        ds.Tables.Add(dtRates);
    }
    //Depots
    using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(sql, DataUtils.ConnectionStrings["TAT"]))
    {
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT cc.* FROM country_depot cc WHERE cc.CountryID = ?iD";
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("iD", ID));
        adapter.Fill(dtDepots);
        ds.Tables.Add(dtDepots);
    }
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: `c.ID ?iD` missing `=` ?

Comment: You should always try your queries in your database manager first by the way. With that, you can be sure it won't work in your code either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you are missing `=` at `c.ID ?iD`:

```
adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT c.*,(Select Initials FROM users WHERE User_ID = c.CreatedByUser) AS CreatedBy, (SELECT Initials FROM users WHERE User_ID = c.ModifiedByUser) AS ModifiedBy " +
                   "FROM countries c WHERE c.Company_ID = ? company_ID AND c.ID = ? iD ORDER BY c.CountryName";
```

Comment: as  Abhik Chakraborty mentioned